# std::index_sequence return size always 1

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, c++14

I am new to C++14 `std::index_sequence`. What does the `size` member for the struct mean? It is always returning one no matter how many elements I created.

```
std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>::size  => 1
std::index_sequence<8, 7, 1, 5>::size => 1
```

I though the return values should be 3 and 4 (the number of elements of that sequence).

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07fb9de4c18ea993); [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) needed.

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (or a SSCCE) it's hard to say anything, but [the answer from TartanLlama](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40612639/440558) is a very good guess. That should have given you compiler warnings though. Don't disregard compiler warnings, they are just as important to fix as errors.

Answer (score 13):

`std::integer_sequence::size` is a function, so you need to call it:

```
std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>::size() => 3
```

You are probably seeing `1` because if you write code like

```
std::cout << std::integer_sequence<int, 1, 2, 3>::size;
```

then the function will be implicitly converted to a function pointer, then to `bool`, and the value will be `true` since the pointer is not null.

Comment: I am just curious. Why a function pointer is converted to bool in cout?

Comment: And  compiler should warn about it.

Comment: @MayurK Because there's an `operator<<` overload for `std::ostream` and `bool`, but not one for function pointers, and function pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`.

Comment: @MayurK: Because it's a legal conversion that allows the code to compile. That's how implicit conversions work; it searches for available conversions until it finds one that makes the code work.